# iOS 13 UISearchBar appearance and behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, ios13

I have my `UISearchBar` set up as follows:

```
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false // Allow user to tap on results
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search patients" // Placeholder
searchController.searchBar.barStyle = .blackOpaque
searchController.searchBar.tintColor = colors.text // Cancel button tint

navigationItem.searchController = searchController // Set the searchController
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true // Auto-hide search when user scrolls
```

This is how it looks on iOS 12: [image: iOS 12 appearance]
vs iOS 13: [image]
What's changed in iOS 13? I've tried going through the different `barStyles`, and also setting `.isTranslucent` to false - no effect for either. Light/dark mode also don't change anything.

The other change is hiding the search bar - on iOS 12 if I scrolled upwards a little the search bar would hide (didn't matter if the table was populated or not). With iOS 13, once the search bar has appeared (ie the user has swiped down), it cannot be hidden again. Anyone know of a fix for this too?

Comment: Did you try searchBar.searchBarStyle = .prominent ??

Comment: @souvickcse Just tried, makes no difference unfortunately

Comment: I’ve pretty much given up on large titles and search for iOS 13. It’s a huge cluster. :(

Comment: I had so much trouble getting the same look for iOS 13 on my semi-translucent search bar. I ended up with 60 lines of code, replacing the original background view with my own.

Comment: @fl034 Have a look at my own answer

Answer (score 22):

I get something similar problem with you. I don't know why this happen in currently iOS 13 and work properly in older version. But i have found the solution by adding this function to your searchBar.

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
   searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
```

**Preview after fixing:**

[image: before fixing]
[image: after fixing]

Comment: `searchBar.backgroundColor` is for iOS lower than 13 then?

Answer (score 10):

How about to use `searchBarStyle` as `default` and change the `searchTextField` background color?

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    searchBar.searchBarStyle = .default
    searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For setting in globally like in `AppDelegate`:

```
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).backgroundColor = .anyColor
}
```

Comment: Any reason that `UISearchBar.appearance().searchTextField.backgroundColor = .anyColor` wouldn't work here?

Comment: This is what I used to fix my SearchBar input field background: `UITextField.appearance().backgroundColor = .white`. Solved my issue for iOS 15 and 16!

Answer (score 4):

`searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.black` does the job as a workaround. The selector is new in iOS 13.

I've filed a report on feedback assistant anyway as I do believe this to be unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

iOS 13+.

```
searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```